# Sometimes tasks in serial DispatchQueue will run concurrently with timer that scheduled in same queue?

Tags: swift, macos, grand-central-dispatch

I have met a thread conflict issue that the task in serial queue runs concurrently with timer that in the same serial queue, the probability is very low, but will occur in long run.

below is the example code in swift 3.0.

```
import Foundation

func printTrace(_ str: String) {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
    let strDate = formatter.string(from: Date())
    let tid = pthread_mach_thread_np(pthread_self())
    print("\(strDate) [\(tid)] \(str)")
}

let queue1 = DispatchQueue(label: "timer-test-queue1")
let queue2 = DispatchQueue(label: "timer-test-queue2")

func asyncBlock() {
    printTrace("asyncBlock")
}

func timerBlock() {
    printTrace("timerBlock 1")
    queue2.async {
        queue1.async {
            asyncBlock()
        }
    }
    printTrace("timerBlock 2")
}

let timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(flags: DispatchSource.TimerFlags.strict, queue: queue1)
timer.scheduleRepeating(deadline: DispatchTime.now(), interval: Double(0.05/* 50 ms */), leeway: .milliseconds(1))
timer.setEventHandler {
    timerBlock()
}
timer.resume()
```

sometimes will show:
timerBlock 1
asyncBlock
timerBlock 2

the DOC says the serial queue only executes one task at same time, does it include the timer task?